# Могут ли строковые данные в sql запросе быть опасными для базы?

Tags: sql, безопасность

Предположим, я делаю серверное API, которое принимает и обрабатывает полноценные sql запросы к базе, а не только хранимые процедуры. Для обеспечения безопасности у меня есть список заблокированных команд (все, кроме select, insert, update и delete). Предполагая, что все строковые данные в запросе безопасны, я просто вырезаю их из пришедшего на сервер запроса, чтобы они не мешались в поиске опасных команд. Регексп вырезания строк:

```
/(\'|").*[^\\]\1/
```

Можно ли как-то составить sql запрос так, чтобы строковые данные нанесли вред базе данных?

P.S. Чтобы небыло недопониманий, под "строковыми данными" я подразумеваю данные, которые записаны внутри строковых литералов с `'` или `"`. Например в этом запросе: `select * from users where name="Vasya"`, `"Vasya"` является строковыми данными.

Comment: если я правильно  понял? но что мешает написать в select `что-то` from `что-то` where a=a; например

Comment: вообще процедуры для того и созданы, чтобы избавиться от прямых запросов к базе, плюс в процедуре можно еще раз проверить данные, и если что-то пошло не так откатить транзакцию

Comment: @Dmitriy select писать можно, этому никто препятствовать не станет. Команду drop, например писать нельзя, за такое мой скрипт забанит. Но вопрос вообще не об этом.

Comment: запрос с условием true ( типо where a=a , или where 1=1 ) выполнится?

Comment: @Dmitriy да, выполнится.

Comment: и вернёт всю таблицу? ну так значит это небезопасно.

Comment: @Dmitriy там у меня тоже есть заморочки: результат запроса попадает во временную таблицу, откуда `drop column`ом удаляются все защищённые поля типа пароля.

Comment: неплохо придумано, но всё равно доступ несанкционированный доступ к БД есть

Comment: `"Vasya"` - это не строковый литерал, а имя колонки. Строковый литерал в sql может быть записан только вот так: `'Vasya'`

Comment: @PavelMayorov в моём примере тоже строковый литерал. Для их записи существуют два вида кавычек.

Comment: @Diskyp второй тип кавычек не для них

Comment: @PavelMayorov я специально загуглил и на всех сайтах с первых страниц гугла не упоминалось о различии в кавычках. Вот один из примеров: http://oracleplsql.ru/literals-mysql.html Можете дать ссылку на ресурс, подробно объясняющий различие?

Comment: @Diskyp ну так сразу и писали бы что mysql используете. Зачем вы общий тэг поставили?

Comment: @PavelMayorov в тэге было указано, что это для специфичных случаев работы с mysql, а вопрос у меня был по sql синтаксису в целом. Признаюсь, не знал о подобных различиях.

Answer (score 1):

Строковые литералы сами по себе всегда безопасны. Но ведь у вас регулярка неправильная! Строка в двойных кавычках в sql - это не литерал строки, а идентификатор... И сколько еще таких ошибок таит загадочный скрипт?

Гораздо лучше если вы воспользуетесь возможностями СУБД: заведёте отдельного ограниченного пользователя и будете выполнять чужие запросы от его имени.

Comment: Если честно, то можно было ограничиться первым предложением и как-то его подкрепить. Спасибо за участие.